# scrollview inside popover not scrolling top in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uipopovercontroller

I am using an iPad ..

In that there is a popover controller .

now when I open up the keyboard then popover gets small in size .

I have connected scrollview in that popover . but somehow its not going to top .. it stuck in between however it goes to contest size but all of them are not above.

how to go to the top area when I have small popover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting the `autoresizingMask` of the scrollView like this:

```
scrollView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```